# running multiple parallel processes in parallel R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, runjags

I run Bayesian statistical models with each chain on a separate processing node using the `runjags` package in R. I want to fit multiple models at onceby nesting `run.jags` calls in a parallel loop using the `foreach` package. However, this often results in error messages, likely because the `foreach` loop doesn't "know" that within the loop I am calling other parallel processes, and so cores are probably double-allocated (or something). Here is an example error message:

> Error in { : 
>         task 2 failed - "The following error was encountered while attempting to run the JAGS model:
>          Error in socketConnection("localhost", port = port, server = TRUE, blocking = TRUE,  : 
>         cannot open the connection

Here is some example code to generate data and fit two models, that request 2 cores each (requiring a total of 4 cores, which I have on my laptop). I would love to find a solution that would allow me to run multiple parallel JAGS models, in parallel. In reality I am running 5-10 models at a time which each require 3 cores, on a cluster.

```
library(foreach)
library(runjags)

#generate a random variable, mean of 25, sd = 5.----
y.list <- list()
for(i in 1:2){
  y.list[[i]] <- rnorm(100, 25, sd = 5)
}

#Specify a JAGS model to fit an intercept.----
jags.model = "
model{
  for(i in 1:N){
    y.hat[i] <- intercept
    y[i] ~ dnorm(y.hat[i], tau)
  }

  #specify priors.
  intercept ~ dnorm(0,1E-3)
  tau <- pow(sigma, -2)
  sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
}
"

n.cores <- 4
registerDoParallel(n.cores)

#Fit models in parallel, with chains running in parallel.----
#two processes that each require two cores (4 cores are registered and all that is required.)
output <- list()
output <- 
foreach(i = 1:length(y.list)) %dopar% {
    #specify data object.
    jd <- list(y=y.list[[i]], N = length(y.list[[i]]))
    #fit model.
    jags.out <- run.jags(jags.model,
                         data=jd,
                         n.chains=2,
                         monitor=c('intercept','tau'),
                         method='rjparallel')
    #return output
    return(jags.out)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to run your sample, but the following vignette should help you out.

You may want to try to use the foreach nesting operator %:%

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf

```
foreach(i = 1:length(y.list)) %:% {
    #specify data object.
    jd <- list(y=y.list[[i]], N = length(y.list[[i]]))
    #fit model.
    jags.out <- run.jags(jags.model,
                         data=jd,
                         n.chains=2,
                         monitor=c('intercept','tau'),
                         method='rjparallel')
    #return output
    return(jags.out)
}
```

Comment: Super interesting. Just dropping the nesting operator only gets the first model run, and returns the error: `Error in inherits(e2, "foreach") : no function to return from, jumping to top level`

Comment: Okay, I've thoroughly read the suggested documentation. It seems like exactly what I want, IF my nested parallel process was another `foreach()` loop. Unfortunately its not, and I don't know what type of parallel construct is running under the hood of `run.jags()`, only that there is one.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to consider here- how to nest parallel `foreach()` loops in general, and how to solve this particular issue.

The solution to nesting parallel `foreach()` loops comes from @Carlos Santillan's answer below, and is a based on a vignette that can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf). Lets say we have one inner loop nested within an outer loop, similar to the problem above, however instead of the parallel call to `run.jags` we have a parallel `foreach()` call:

```
outer_list <- list()
#begin outer loop:
outer_list <-
foreach(i = 1:length(some_index)) %:% {
    #grab something to feed next foreach loop.
    to_inner <- grab_data[[i]]

    #Do something in a nested foreach loop.
    inner_list <- list()
    #begin inner loop:
    inner_list <-
    foreach(k = 1:some_index) %dopar% {
      #do some other function.
      out_inner <- some_function(to_inner)
      return(out_inner)
      }
   out_outer <- some_function(out_inner)
   return(out_outer)
}
```

The key is using the `%:%` operator in the outer loop, and the `%dopar%` operator in the inner loop.

This will not solve the above `run.jags()` nested parallel problem however, since it is not a nested `foreach()` loop. To solve this particular nested `run.jags()` problem I changed the `method` setting in run.jags to `method=parallel` instead of `method=rjparallel`. `run.jags()` has multiple different parallel implementations and this particular one seems to work based on my timing analyses. Hopefully in the future there will be a more definitive answer as to *why* this works. I just know that it does work.